# Proper way to change font size instantaneously without any easing in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

I just went in manually and added a single frame before the change in font size a frame where the font is the previous size. Is manually adding a frame one frame before the change the best way to make the font change in size instantaneously or is there a more formal way of doing it?

I also tried changing the easing to be instantaneous by going in a single frame prior and adjusting the easing speed to be 100% in a single frame as well, which worked.

I just don't want the frame time stops section to get messy with so many time stops. Is this the right way to do it still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a hold keyframe. Right click the keyframe, select hold frame.

Each time the play head gets to a hold frame, the value will jump to that keyframe value with no interpolation.

https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/keyframe-interpolation.html